# Modifying manifest file deletes indexdb in windows 8 metro app

Tags: windows-8, winjs, indexeddb

My app(windows 8 metro, using javascript) uses indexDb for database, i have seen when i modify manifest file indexDB database is deleted.

Is this a bug or a feature??.

Now my app is already in windows store I am afraid if i will modify manifest file (which i want to do) users database will get deleted and that will be a huge loss to the user.

So what is the work around for this problem.

You can try their official demo and you will find the same problem
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/IndexedDB-sample-eb1e95af

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug - when you modify manifest and deploy app using Visual Studio local data is cleared. This behavior is the same for JS, C++ and C# projects.

It will not happen to your users when they will update the app through the Store.

Comment: in past i modified app-manifest file (for app update) and users reported(thru email) that their data was cleared. That's why iam afraid of modifying app-manifest file, which i actually want to do.